# Is there a Webpack plugin to identify SCSS duplicate imports?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a large React application with Webpack and SCSS. In this app I have several components and some of them have their own SCSS file.

Is there any Webpack plugin (or other tool) to detect SCSS duplicated @imports? As I would like to detect these cases and improve them.

Comment: What did you [already search for](/help/how-to-ask), and what did you find that didn't quite address the issue you're facing? Just so that folks don't end up recommending ten different things, all of which you already tried but didn't mention.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You're right Mike! Basically, i searched this same question and find out the REAL solution is replacing import with use, sadly, this isn't posible in our app currently, so i would like to know if there's a way to detect these duplicates to fix them manually.

I also checked https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/ but it may not be the same as we're currently using SASS and not css.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No, don't tell "me", tell everyone who might see your question by [editing your post](/help/how-to-ask).